# Javascript Autocomplete Results List Below The Input Field

Tags: javascript, css

I've been trying to show all the autocomplete items below the input field. But, the alignment of the results isn't right:

### Demo

```js
function friendly_url(str, max) {
    if (max === undefined) max = 32;
    var a_chars = new Array(
        new Array("a", /[Ã¡Ã Ã¢Ã£ÂªÃÃ€Ã‚Ãƒ]/g),
        new Array("e", /[Ã©Ã¨ÃªÃ‰ÃˆÃŠ]/g),
        new Array("i", /[Ã­Ã¬Ã®ÃÃŒÃŽ]/g),
        new Array("o", /[Ã²Ã³Ã´ÃµÂºÃ“Ã’Ã”Ã•]/g),
        new Array("u", /[ÃºÃ¹Ã»ÃšÃ™Ã›]/g),
        new Array("c", /[Ã§Ã‡]/g),
        new Array("n", /[Ã‘Ã±]/g)
    );
    // Replace vowel with accent without them
    for (var i = 0; i < a_chars.length; i++)
        str = str.replace(a_chars[i][1], a_chars[i][0]);
    // first replace whitespace by -, second remove repeated - by just one, third turn in low case the chars,
    // fourth delete all chars which are not between a-z or 0-9, fifth trim the string and
    // the last step truncate the string to 32 chars
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\-]/g, '').replace(/\-{2,}/g, '-').replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, '').substr(0, max);
}


var autoComplete = function() {
    function a(a) {
        function b(a, b) {
            return a.classList ? a.classList.contains(b) : new RegExp("\\b" + b + "\\b").test(a.className)
        }

        function c(a, b, c) {
            a.attachEvent ? a.attachEvent("on" + b, c) : a.addEventListener(b, c)
        }

        function d(a, b, c) {
            a.detachEvent ? a.detachEvent("on" + b, c) : a.removeEventListener(b, c)
        }

        function e(a, d, e, f) {
            c(f || document, d, function(c) {
                for (var d, f = c.target || c.srcElement; f && !(d = b(f, a));) f = f.parentElement;
                d && e.call(f, c)
            })
        }
        if (document.querySelector) {
            var f = {
                selector: 0,
                source: 0,
                minChars: 3,
                delay: 150,
                offsetLeft: 0,
                offsetTop: 1,
                cache: 1,
                menuClass: "",
                renderItem: function(a, b) {
                    b = b.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
                    var c = new RegExp("(" + b.split(" ").join("|") + ")", "gi");
                    return '<li class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + a + '"><a class="click_fast" href="./?buscar=' + friendly_url(a) + '">' + a.replace(c, "<b>$1</b>") + "</a></li>"
                },
                onSelect: function(a, b, c) {}
            };
            for (var g in a) a.hasOwnProperty(g) && (f[g] = a[g]);
            for (var h = "object" == typeof f.selector ? [f.selector] : document.querySelectorAll(f.selector), i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
                var j = h[i];
                j.sc = document.createElement("ul"), j.sc.className = "auto-complete" + f.menuClass, j.autocompleteAttr = j.getAttribute("autocomplete"), j.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off"), j.cache = {}, j.last_val = "", j.updateSC = function(a, b) {
                    var c = j.getBoundingClientRect();
                    if (j.sc.style.width = Math.round(c.right - c.left) + "px", !a && (j.sc.style.display = "block", j.sc.maxHeight || (j.sc.maxHeight = parseInt((window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(j.sc, null) : j.sc.currentStyle).maxHeight)), j.sc.suggestionHeight || (j.sc.suggestionHeight = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion").offsetHeight), j.sc.suggestionHeight))
                        if (b) {
                            var d = j.sc.scrollTop,
                                e = b.getBoundingClientRect().top - j.sc.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                            e + j.sc.suggestionHeight - j.sc.maxHeight > 0 ? j.sc.scrollTop = e + j.sc.suggestionHeight + d - j.sc.maxHeight : 0 > e && (j.sc.scrollTop = e + d)
                        } else j.sc.scrollTop = 0
                }, c(window, "resize", j.updateSC), $("#search").after(j.sc), e("autocomplete-suggestion", "mouseleave", function(a) {
                    var b = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion.selected");
                    b && setTimeout(function() {
                        b.className = b.className.replace("selected", "")
                    }, 20)
                }, j.sc), e("autocomplete-suggestion", "mouseover", function(a) {
                    var b = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion.selected");
                    b && (b.className = b.className.replace("selected", "")), this.className += " selected"
                }, j.sc), e("autocomplete-suggestion", "mousedown", function(a) {
                    if (b(this, "autocomplete-suggestion")) {
                        var c = this.getAttribute("data-val");
                        j.value = c, f.onSelect(a, c, this), j.sc.style.display = "none"
                    }
                }, j.sc), j.blurHandler = function() {
                    try {
                        var a = document.querySelector(".auto-complete:hover")
                    } catch (a) {
                        var a
                    }
                    a ? j !== document.activeElement && setTimeout(function() {
                        j.focus()
                    }, 20) : (j.last_val = j.value, j.sc.style.display = "none", setTimeout(function() {
                        j.sc.style.display = "none"
                    }, 350))
                }, c(j, "blur", j.blurHandler);
                var k = function(a) {
                    var b = j.value;
                    if (j.cache[b] = a, a.length && b.length >= f.minChars) {
                        for (var c = "", d = 0; d < a.length; d++) c += f.renderItem(a[d], b);
                        j.sc.innerHTML = c, j.updateSC(0)
                    } else j.sc.style.display = "none"
                };
                j.keydownHandler = function(a) {
                    var b = window.event ? a.keyCode : a.which;
                    if ((40 == b || 38 == b) && j.sc.innerHTML) {
                        var c, d = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion.selected");
                        return d ? (c = 40 == b ? d.nextSibling : d.previousSibling, c ? (d.className = d.className.replace("selected", ""), c.className += " selected", j.value = c.getAttribute("data-val")) : (d.className = d.className.replace("selected", ""), j.value = j.last_val, c = 0)) : (c = 40 == b ? j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion") : j.sc.childNodes[j.sc.childNodes.length - 1], c.className += " selected", j.value = c.getAttribute("data-val")), j.updateSC(0, c), !1
                    }
                    if (27 == b) j.value = j.last_val, j.sc.style.display = "none";
                    else if (13 == b || 9 == b) {
                        var d = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion.selected");
                        d && "none" != j.sc.style.display && (f.onSelect(a, d.getAttribute("data-val"), d), setTimeout(function() {
                            j.sc.style.display = "none"
                        }, 20))
                    }
                }, c(j, "keydown", j.keydownHandler), j.keyupHandler = function(a) {
                    var b = window.event ? a.keyCode : a.which;
                    if (!b || (35 > b || b > 40) && 13 != b && 27 != b) {
                        var c = j.value;
                        if (c.length >= f.minChars) {
                            if (c != j.last_val) {
                                if (j.last_val = c, clearTimeout(j.timer), f.cache) {
                                    if (c in j.cache) return void k(j.cache[c]);
                                    for (var d = 1; d < c.length - f.minChars; d++) {
                                        var e = c.slice(0, c.length - d);
                                        if (e in j.cache && !j.cache[e].length) return void k([])
                                    }
                                }
                                j.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                                    f.source(c, k)
                                }, f.delay)
                            }
                        } else j.last_val = c, j.sc.style.display = "none"
                    }
                }, c(j, "keyup", j.keyupHandler), j.focusHandler = function(a) {
                    j.last_val = "\n", j.keyupHandler(a)
                }, f.minChars || c(j, "focus", j.focusHandler)
            }
            this.destroy = function() {
                for (var a = 0; a < h.length; a++) {
                    var b = h[a];
                    d(window, "resize", b.updateSC), d(b, "blur", b.blurHandler), d(b, "focus", b.focusHandler), d(b, "keydown", b.keydownHandler), d(b, "keyup", b.keyupHandler), b.autocompleteAttr ? b.setAttribute("autocomplete", b.autocompleteAttr) : b.removeAttribute("autocomplete"), document.body.removeChild(b.sc), b = null
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return a
}();
! function() {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("autoComplete", function() {
        return autoComplete
    }) : "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = autoComplete : window.autoComplete = autoComplete
}(), $(function() {
    new autoComplete({
        selector: "#search",
        minChars: 1,
        source: function(a, b) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=" + a,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(a) {
                    b(a[1])
                }
            })
        },
        onSelect: function(a, b, c) {
            location.href = './?buscar=' + friendly_url(b);
            $(".frm_search").submit()
        }
    })
});
```

```css
button,
input {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.15;
    margin: 0
}

button,
input {
    overflow: visible
}

button {
    text-transform: none
}

[type=reset],
[type=submit],
button,
html [type=button] {
    -webkit-appearance: button
}

[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0
}

[type=button]:-moz-focusring,
[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,
[type=submit]:-moz-focusring,
button:-moz-focusring {
    outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
}

[type=checkbox],
[type=radio] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0
}

[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto
}

[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    outline-offset: -2px
}

[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    font: inherit
}

[hidden] {
    display: none
}

html {
    height: 100%
}

button,
input {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.searchBoxBar {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 15px
}

.searchBoxBar form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 790px;
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-radius: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field {
    height: 55px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input {
    height: 100%;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input.placeholder {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 16px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 16px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 16px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input:focus,
.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: 0
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap {
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap input {
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .svg-wrapper {
    min-width: 80px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap svg {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    fill: #222
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap {
    min-width: 216px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap .btn-search {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #00ad5f;
    transition: all .2s ease-out, color .2s ease-out;
    font-weight: 300
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap .btn-search:hover {
    background: #009451
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap .btn-search:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field {
        height: 50px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .svg-wrapper {
        min-width: 40px;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 10px
    }
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap svg {
        width: 26px;
        height: 26px;
        fill: #222
    }
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap {
        min-width: 100px
    }
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap .btn-search {
        font-size: 13px
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="author" content="colorlib.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
   <style>
     .auto-complete
     {
     z-index:9999;
     position: absolute;
     }
   </style>
   <body>
     <div class="searchBoxBar">
     <form>
      <div class="inner-form">
        <div class="input-field first-wrap">
          <div class="svg-wrapper">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
           </svg>
         </div>
         <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
         <ul class="autocompletador" style="display: none; width: 372px;"></ul>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field second-wrap">
            <button class="btn-search" type="button">SEARCH</button>
         </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>

   </body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
 </html>
```

I've set the z-index CSS property as well. But all the results arent showing just below the input field.

```css
{
     z-index:9999;
     position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class name from `autocompletador` to `auto-complete` from the below element in your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht43xjey/1/)

```html
<ul class="autocompletador" style="display: none; width: 372px;"></ul>
```

It will be like this:

```html
<ul class="auto-complete" style="display: none; width: 372px;"></ul>
```

and

Change the style of `auto-complete` in this way:

```css
.auto-complete {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
}
```

If you want more spaces above the list of results, just increase the value of the `top`. Here is the working example:

```js
function friendly_url(str, max) {
    if (max === undefined) max = 32;
    var a_chars = new Array(
        new Array("a", /[Ã¡Ã Ã¢Ã£ÂªÃÃ€Ã‚Ãƒ]/g),
        new Array("e", /[Ã©Ã¨ÃªÃ‰ÃˆÃŠ]/g),
        new Array("i", /[Ã­Ã¬Ã®ÃÃŒÃŽ]/g),
        new Array("o", /[Ã²Ã³Ã´ÃµÂºÃ“Ã’Ã”Ã•]/g),
        new Array("u", /[ÃºÃ¹Ã»ÃšÃ™Ã›]/g),
        new Array("c", /[Ã§Ã‡]/g),
        new Array("n", /[Ã‘Ã±]/g)
    );
    // Replace vowel with accent without them
    for (var i = 0; i < a_chars.length; i++)
        str = str.replace(a_chars[i][1], a_chars[i][0]);
    // first replace whitespace by -, second remove repeated - by just one, third turn in low case the chars,
    // fourth delete all chars which are not between a-z or 0-9, fifth trim the string and
    // the last step truncate the string to 32 chars
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\-]/g, '').replace(/\-{2,}/g, '-').replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, '').substr(0, max);
}


var autoComplete = function() {
    function a(a) {
        function b(a, b) {
            return a.classList ? a.classList.contains(b) : new RegExp("\\b" + b + "\\b").test(a.className)
        }

        function c(a, b, c) {
            a.attachEvent ? a.attachEvent("on" + b, c) : a.addEventListener(b, c)
        }

        function d(a, b, c) {
            a.detachEvent ? a.detachEvent("on" + b, c) : a.removeEventListener(b, c)
        }

        function e(a, d, e, f) {
            c(f || document, d, function(c) {
                for (var d, f = c.target || c.srcElement; f && !(d = b(f, a));) f = f.parentElement;
                d && e.call(f, c)
            })
        }
        if (document.querySelector) {
            var f = {
                selector: 0,
                source: 0,
                minChars: 3,
                delay: 150,
                offsetLeft: 0,
                offsetTop: 1,
                cache: 1,
                menuClass: "",
                renderItem: function(a, b) {
                    b = b.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
                    var c = new RegExp("(" + b.split(" ").join("|") + ")", "gi");
                    return '<li class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + a + '"><a class="click_fast" href="./?buscar=' + friendly_url(a) + '">' + a.replace(c, "<b>$1</b>") + "</a></li>"
                },
                onSelect: function(a, b, c) {}
            };
            for (var g in a) a.hasOwnProperty(g) && (f[g] = a[g]);
            for (var h = "object" == typeof f.selector ? [f.selector] : document.querySelectorAll(f.selector), i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
                var j = h[i];
                j.sc = document.createElement("ul"), j.sc.className = "auto-complete" + f.menuClass, j.autocompleteAttr = j.getAttribute("autocomplete"), j.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off"), j.cache = {}, j.last_val = "", j.updateSC = function(a, b) {
                    var c = j.getBoundingClientRect();
                    if (j.sc.style.width = Math.round(c.right - c.left) + "px", !a && (j.sc.style.display = "block", j.sc.maxHeight || (j.sc.maxHeight = parseInt((window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(j.sc, null) : j.sc.currentStyle).maxHeight)), j.sc.suggestionHeight || (j.sc.suggestionHeight = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion").offsetHeight), j.sc.suggestionHeight))
                        if (b) {
                            var d = j.sc.scrollTop,
                                e = b.getBoundingClientRect().top - j.sc.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                            e + j.sc.suggestionHeight - j.sc.maxHeight > 0 ? j.sc.scrollTop = e + j.sc.suggestionHeight + d - j.sc.maxHeight : 0 > e && (j.sc.scrollTop = e + d)
                        } else j.sc.scrollTop = 0
                }, c(window, "resize", j.updateSC), $("#search").after(j.sc), e("autocomplete-suggestion", "mouseleave", function(a) {
                    var b = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion.selected");
                    b && setTimeout(function() {
                        b.className = b.className.replace("selected", "")
                    }, 20)
                }, j.sc), e("autocomplete-suggestion", "mouseover", function(a) {
                    var b = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion.selected");
                    b && (b.className = b.className.replace("selected", "")), this.className += " selected"
                }, j.sc), e("autocomplete-suggestion", "mousedown", function(a) {
                    if (b(this, "autocomplete-suggestion")) {
                        var c = this.getAttribute("data-val");
                        j.value = c, f.onSelect(a, c, this), j.sc.style.display = "none"
                    }
                }, j.sc), j.blurHandler = function() {
                    try {
                        var a = document.querySelector(".auto-complete:hover")
                    } catch (a) {
                        var a
                    }
                    a ? j !== document.activeElement && setTimeout(function() {
                        j.focus()
                    }, 20) : (j.last_val = j.value, j.sc.style.display = "none", setTimeout(function() {
                        j.sc.style.display = "none"
                    }, 350))
                }, c(j, "blur", j.blurHandler);
                var k = function(a) {
                    var b = j.value;
                    if (j.cache[b] = a, a.length && b.length >= f.minChars) {
                        for (var c = "", d = 0; d < a.length; d++) c += f.renderItem(a[d], b);
                        j.sc.innerHTML = c, j.updateSC(0)
                    } else j.sc.style.display = "none"
                };
                j.keydownHandler = function(a) {
                    var b = window.event ? a.keyCode : a.which;
                    if ((40 == b || 38 == b) && j.sc.innerHTML) {
                        var c, d = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion.selected");
                        return d ? (c = 40 == b ? d.nextSibling : d.previousSibling, c ? (d.className = d.className.replace("selected", ""), c.className += " selected", j.value = c.getAttribute("data-val")) : (d.className = d.className.replace("selected", ""), j.value = j.last_val, c = 0)) : (c = 40 == b ? j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion") : j.sc.childNodes[j.sc.childNodes.length - 1], c.className += " selected", j.value = c.getAttribute("data-val")), j.updateSC(0, c), !1
                    }
                    if (27 == b) j.value = j.last_val, j.sc.style.display = "none";
                    else if (13 == b || 9 == b) {
                        var d = j.sc.querySelector(".autocomplete-suggestion.selected");
                        d && "none" != j.sc.style.display && (f.onSelect(a, d.getAttribute("data-val"), d), setTimeout(function() {
                            j.sc.style.display = "none"
                        }, 20))
                    }
                }, c(j, "keydown", j.keydownHandler), j.keyupHandler = function(a) {
                    var b = window.event ? a.keyCode : a.which;
                    if (!b || (35 > b || b > 40) && 13 != b && 27 != b) {
                        var c = j.value;
                        if (c.length >= f.minChars) {
                            if (c != j.last_val) {
                                if (j.last_val = c, clearTimeout(j.timer), f.cache) {
                                    if (c in j.cache) return void k(j.cache[c]);
                                    for (var d = 1; d < c.length - f.minChars; d++) {
                                        var e = c.slice(0, c.length - d);
                                        if (e in j.cache && !j.cache[e].length) return void k([])
                                    }
                                }
                                j.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                                    f.source(c, k)
                                }, f.delay)
                            }
                        } else j.last_val = c, j.sc.style.display = "none"
                    }
                }, c(j, "keyup", j.keyupHandler), j.focusHandler = function(a) {
                    j.last_val = "\n", j.keyupHandler(a)
                }, f.minChars || c(j, "focus", j.focusHandler)
            }
            this.destroy = function() {
                for (var a = 0; a < h.length; a++) {
                    var b = h[a];
                    d(window, "resize", b.updateSC), d(b, "blur", b.blurHandler), d(b, "focus", b.focusHandler), d(b, "keydown", b.keydownHandler), d(b, "keyup", b.keyupHandler), b.autocompleteAttr ? b.setAttribute("autocomplete", b.autocompleteAttr) : b.removeAttribute("autocomplete"), document.body.removeChild(b.sc), b = null
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return a
}();
! function() {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("autoComplete", function() {
        return autoComplete
    }) : "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = autoComplete : window.autoComplete = autoComplete
}(), $(function() {
    new autoComplete({
        selector: "#search",
        minChars: 1,
        source: function(a, b) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=" + a,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(a) {
                    b(a[1])
                }
            })
        },
        onSelect: function(a, b, c) {
            location.href = './?buscar=' + friendly_url(b);
            $(".frm_search").submit()
        }
    })
});
```

```css
button,
input {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.15;
    margin: 0
}

button,
input {
    overflow: visible
}

button {
    text-transform: none
}

[type=reset],
[type=submit],
button,
html [type=button] {
    -webkit-appearance: button
}

[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0
}

[type=button]:-moz-focusring,
[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,
[type=submit]:-moz-focusring,
button:-moz-focusring {
    outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
}

[type=checkbox],
[type=radio] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0
}

[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto
}

[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    outline-offset: -2px
}

[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    font: inherit
}

[hidden] {
    display: none
}

html {
    height: 100%
}

button,
input {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.searchBoxBar {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 15px
}

.searchBoxBar form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 790px;
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-radius: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field {
    height: 55px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input {
    height: 100%;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input.placeholder {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 16px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 16px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 16px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input:focus,
.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field input:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: 0
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap {
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap input {
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .svg-wrapper {
    min-width: 80px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap svg {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    fill: #222
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap {
    min-width: 216px
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap .btn-search {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #00ad5f;
    transition: all .2s ease-out, color .2s ease-out;
    font-weight: 300
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap .btn-search:hover {
    background: #009451
}

.searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap .btn-search:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field {
        height: 50px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .svg-wrapper {
        min-width: 40px;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 10px
    }
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap svg {
        width: 26px;
        height: 26px;
        fill: #222
    }
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap {
        min-width: 100px
    }
    .searchBoxBar form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap .btn-search {
        font-size: 13px
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="author" content="colorlib.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
   <style>
     .auto-complete{
         z-index:9999;
         position: absolute;
         top: 80px;
     }
   </style>
   <body>
     <div class="searchBoxBar">
     <form>
      <div class="inner-form">
        <div class="input-field first-wrap">
          <div class="svg-wrapper">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
           </svg>
         </div>
         <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
         <ul class="auto-complete" style="display: none; width: 372px;"></ul>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field second-wrap">
            <button class="btn-search" type="button">SEARCH</button>
         </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>

   </body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
 </html>
```